# todonotes breaks pgfplots and tikz spy with externalization

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, todonotes

I want to use todonotes in a document that also uses pgfplots, tikz spy and tikz external. Unfortunately, todonotes breaks the layout of pgfplots figures as illustrated by the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\tikzexternalize
[
  mode=list and make,
  % Does not help
  optimize command away={\todo}{1},
]

% Disable externalization for \todo in order to avoid compilation errors.
\xpretocmd\todo{%
  \bgroup\tikzexternaldisable
}{}{}

\xapptocmd\todo{%
  \egroup
}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tb]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      spy using outlines={%
        connect spies,
        rectangle,
      }
    ]
    \begin{axis}
      [
        xmin=0,xmax=320,
        ymin=0,ymax=300,
      ]

      \coordinate (spyat) at (292,223);
      \coordinate (magat) at (150,90);
    \end{axis}

    \spy[thick] on (spyat) in node at (magat);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

% Adding todo does not work
\lipsum\todo{foo}\lipsum
% Works!
%\lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}
```

This is how the figure looks like:
[image: Wrong]

And this is how the figure supposed to look:
[image: Correct]

One way to avoid the broken layout is either not to use `todonotes` or to disable externalization altogether. The latter is however not an option.

Is there any other way to overcome the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question. `\pgfsyspdfmark` written to the `.aux` file seems to be responsible for the broken layout. Hence, disabling its usage in externalized documents as follows

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\tikzexternalrealjob}{\pgfactualjobname}}{}{%
  \renewcommand\pgfsyspdfmark[3]{}%
}
```

solves the problem. This check requires the `ifthen` package.

Alternatively, one can use the `\tikzifexternalizing` command, as suggested in the comments by Max Snippe:

```
\tikzifexternalizing{%
  \renewcommand\pgfsyspdfmark[3]{}%
}{}
```

Comment: You could probably also use `\tikzifexternalizing{<true code>}{<false code>}`.

Comment: True, this seems to work as well.